# How are shell commands executed and in what context do they run?

Tags: ubuntu, go

In a golang http application server, golang has CPU threads to use and it creates go routines to respond to http requests and responses.

So if my application is getting 100 requests per second, golang will handle this just fine.

Now say for each http request, I am making a shell command to execute a command line argument.

How is this process handled?

I want to understand how shell commands are managed when they are executed from a web application, and if there is some threading model that manages the execution process of these commands.

Comment: "it creates channels to respond to http requests and responses" no, `net/http` spawns a goroutine for each request, not a channel. Shell commands are executed the same as in any other application, Go or otherwise, web or otherwise: a new process is forked. The Go scheduler is not involved; the new process has its own threads that are up to it to manage.

Comment: sorry I meant to say go routine no channel :)

Comment: "I want to understand how shell commands are managed when they are executed from a web application" They are managed in the same way as in a non-web-application: New OS processes. Nothing to see here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q:** "Is [there] some threading model that manages the execution process of these commands?"

**A:** No.

If you spawn a shell (regardless if it's an Apache CGI handler, a [popen()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html),  the command line ... or a goroutine), you spawn a new shell process.

Worse, a shell script typically spawns many *OTHER* shell subprocesses.

Additionally, spawning *nix shells in response to a web request could potentially be a *HUGE* security risk, if you have an Internet-facing web site.

Comment: I know it is a bad idea, just trying to understand what goes on under the covers.